# iTunes has expired, I can't install the latest version of iTunes because the expired one is 'newer'

Tags: macos, itunes

Any ideas what I should do? It' sa bit weird that it won't let me run iTunes claiming it's expired and when I try to download a new version of it (10.4) the installer locks me saying iTunes is newer..

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the old version first, and then install the latest version. If you're getting an expired message, then you're likely using one of the pre-release versions that's for beta testing.

Comment: I tried to uninstall it (move to trash from application folder) but it said that iTunes is required by OSX to function

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue! However, if you drop the itunes app into the program *CleanMyMac* and drag it into the *Uninstall application* section, itunes will be uninstalled from your computer and then you can reinstall the *older* 10.4 version.